# ProcessPoolExecutor overhead ?? parallel processing takes more time than single process for large size matrix operation

Tags: python, numpy

My python code contains a numpy dot operation of huge size (over 2^(tens...)) matrix and vector.
To reduce the computing time, I applied parallel processing by dividing the matrix suited for the number of cpu cores.
I used `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.
My issue is that the parallel processing takes much more time than single processing.

The following is my code.

1. single process code.

```
self._vector = np.dot(matrix, self._vector)
```

2. parallel processing code.

```
    each_worker_coverage = int(self._dimension/self.workers)
         args = []
         for i in range(self.workers):
             if (i+1)*each_worker_coverage < self._dimension:
                 arg = [i, gate[i*each_worker_coverage:(i+1)*each_worker_coverage], self._vector]
             else:
                 arg = [i, gate[i*each_worker_coverage:self._dimension], self._vector]
             args.append(arg)
         pool = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(self.workers)
         results = list(pool.map(innerproduct, args, chunksize=1))
         for result in results:
             if (result[0]+1)*each_worker_coverage < self._dimension:
                 self._vector[result[0]*each_worker_coverage:(result[0]+1)*each_worker_coverage] = result[1]
             else:
                 self._vector[result[0]*each_worker_coverage:self._dimension] = result[1]
```

The innerproduct function called in parallel is as follows.

````
def innerproduct(args):
    answer = np.dot(args[1], args[2])
    return args[0], answer
    ```

For a 2^14 x 2^14 matrix and a 2^14 vector, the single process code takes only 0.05 seconds, but the parallel processing code takes 6.2 seconds.
I also checked the time with the `innerproduct` method, and it only takes 0.02~0.03 sec.
I don't understand this situation.
Why does the parallel processing (multi-processing not multi-threading) take more time?
````

Comment: The number of cpu cores is only 4, but for testing, I set the number of workers is 2.

Answer (score 3):

To exactly *know* the cause of the slowdown you would have to *measure* how long everything takes, and with multiprocessing and multithreading that can be tricky.

So what follows is my best guess. For multiprocessing to work, the parent process has to *transfer* the data used in the calculations to the worker processes. The time this takes depends on the amount of data. Transferring a 2^14 x 2^14 matrix is probably going to take a significant amount of time.
I suspect that this data transfer is what is taking the extra time.

If you are using an operating system that uses the `fork` startmethod for `multiprocessing`/`concurrent.futures`, *there is a way around this data transfer*. These operating systems are for example Linux, *BSD but not macOS and ms-windows).

On the abovementioned operating systems, multiprocessing uses the `fork` system call to create its workers. This system call creates a copy of the parent process as the child processes. So if you create the vectors and matrices *before* creating the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, the workers will *inherit* that data. This is not a very costly or time consuming operation because all these OS's use copy-on-write for managing memory pages. As long as the original matrix isn't changed, all programs using it are reading from the same memory pages. This inheriting of the data means you don't have to pass the data explicitly to the worker. You just have to pass a small data structure that says on which index ranges a worker has to operate.

Unfortunately, due to technical limitations of the platform, this doesn't work on macOS and ms-windows. What you *could* do on those systems is store the original matrix and vector memory mapped binary files before you create the `Executor`. If you tag these mappings with a name, the worker processes should be able to map the same data into their memory without having to transfer them. I think is it possible to instruct `numpy` to use such a raw binary array without recreating it.

On both platforms you could use the same technique to "send data back" to the parent process; save the data in shared memory and return the filename or tagname to the parent process.

Comment: Thank you @Roland Smith. As I understand from your answer, by creating large matrix before the fork, it may be possible to reduce such a data transfer overhead. By the way, I already created the matrix before the fork function. I am currently using mac os and linux. Anyway,.. I am trying to find any method to reduce the data transfer cost.

Comment: As an alternative to ProcessPoolExecutor, what about ThreadPoolExecutor? numpy mostly doesn't hold the GIL, so multiple threads should be able to run this in parallel. That would prevent the need to transfer the arrays between processes.

Comment: @NickODell One would have to test that. In the C core of `numpy`, 60-ish uses of the `NPY_END_THREADS` macro can be observed. (There seem to be multipe threading start macros, so ends are easier to check.) Typically, only part of a function has threading enabled. Also keep in mind that the Python code in `numpy` *is* constrained by the GIL.  So I'm not sure if your qualification of *mostly* holds true. Additionally, since code using cannot depend on the GIL for access serialization, one would have to use careful locking to prevent concurrent modification of arrays.

Comment: @RolandSmith All good points. Every codebase is different, so the amount of time code holds the GIL will differ too. A tool like [gil_load](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/gil_load) can be used to measure how much time the GIL is held.

Comment: @NickODell Interesting. However, `gil_load` is documented as Linux-only. I could not get it to load on FreeBSD. Although it could just be that my Cython-fu is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using modern versions of NumPy and OS, it's most likely that

`self._vector = np.dot(matrix, self._vector)`

is already optimized and uses all your CPU cores.

If `np.show_config()` displays `openblas` or `MKL` you may run a simple test:

```
a = np.random.rand(7000, 7000)
b = np.random.rand(7000, 7000)
np.dot(a, b)
```

It should use all CPU cores for a couple of seconds.

If it's not, you may install OpenBLAS or MKL and reinstall NumPy. See [Using MKL to boost Numpy performance on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@black_swan/using-mkl-to-boost-numpy-performance-on-ubuntu-f62781e63c38)